# Find the general solution of the system of ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{cases}x'_t=-\dfrac54x+\dfrac34y+\dfrac2{1+e^t}\\y'_t=\dfrac34x-\dfrac54y\end{cases}$$
I get the eigenvalues $-1/2$ and $-2$, but the number of eigenvectors for $-2$ is $2$, I don't know why.

Comment: Use variation of parameters.

Comment: Do you have an approach? It's important to know what you have tried and what techniques you know.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is not a do-my-homework site, so please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Different eigenvalues should give different eigenvectors! You should get for each eigenvalue exactly one eigenvector

Answer (score 1):

You get, from visual inspection of the symmetry of the coefficient matrix
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x+y)=-\frac12(x+y)+\frac2{1+e^t}\implies e^{t/2}(x+y)=2\arctan(e^{t/2})+C
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x-y)=-2(x-y)+\frac2{1+e^t}\implies e^{2t}(x-y)=2(e^t-\ln(1+e^t))+C
$$
which you now can compare to your solution that you should get from a systematic approach using the eigen-decomposition, fundamental matrix, and variation of constants.